# Carregar ficheiro php com jquery

Tags: php, jquery, load

Olá,

Em primeiro peço desculpa se a pergunta não for bem estruturada.

Estou a contruir um sistema de gestão de conteudo/stocks e afins..
Deixo em baixo um print screen onde tento explicar como esta estrurada as pastas/directorias.

No ficheiro index.php tenho o seguinte:

```
<?PHP
require_once('sistema/functions.php');
require_once('control/head_load_script.php');
corpo_main();
require_once('control/footer.php');
?>
```

No ficheiro root/sistema/functions.php tenho as seguintes funcções:

```
function getLang(){
  if(!empty($_SESSION['usuarioID'])  == '' ){
    if(isSet($_GET['lang'])){
      $lang = $_GET['lang'];

      $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
      setcookie("lang", $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
    } else if(isSet($_SESSION['lang'])){
      $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
    } else if(isSet($_COOKIE['lang'])){
      $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
    } else{
      if(getSystemInfo('site_lang') == ''){
        $lang = "pt";
      } else {
        $lang = getSystemInfo('site_lang');
      }
    }
    include_once 'lang/lang.'.$lang.'.php';
  } else {
    $lang = getuserinfo('lang');
    include_once 'lang/lang.'.$lang.'.php';
  }
  DEFINE('langTag', $lang);
}
getLang();

function corpo_main(){
  if (!isset($_SESSION['usuarioID'])) {
    session_destroy();
    require_once('control/login.php'); 
  } else {
    require_once('control/header.php');
    require_once('control/corpo.php');
  } 
}
```

Nos ficheiros root/lang/lang.pt.php ou lang.en.php tenho o seguinte: (entre outras traduções)

```
DEFINE('users','Utilizadores');
```

No ficheiro root/js/main.js tenho:

```
getPage = function(page,title){
  $("#main-panel-body").empty();
  $( "#main-panel-body" ).load( "control/loader.html" );
  setTimeout(function(){
    $( "#main-panel-body" ).load( "sistema/corpos/"+page+".php" ); 
    $("#main-panel-body").empty();
  }, 2000); 
  document.title = title;
}
```

No ficheiro control/corpo.php, tenho uma DIV Com o ID main-panel-body, quando substituo o conteudo dessa div, atraves do jquery que mostro em cima, pelo conteudo do ficheiro root/sistema/corpos/users.php, não carrega as variaveis em php que o ficheiro users.php tem, como por exemplo variaveis de tradução. Emite um erro.

Deixo em baixo o erro:

Warning: Use of undefined constant users - assumed 'users' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in

O que estou eu a fazer de mal?

Obrigado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Olá, boa noite!

Então, isso na verdade não é um ERRO, e sim um aviso de Atenção, provavelmente você está utilizando um [versão](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration72.deprecated.php) do PHP que não aceita mas a definição de constantes dessa forma.

Exemplo de código atual:

```
<?php
define("title", "Stack Overflow");
echo constant("title");
```

Comment: Não resolve. Corrigi o que me indicou, e agora devolve o erro Warning: Constant(): Couldn't Find Constant Users In

Comment: Colega, está dizendo que não entrou a constante Users, faz o seguinte, posta o código de users.php

Comment: Não. Não entro. O codigo de users.php não é nenhum por enquanto. Tens apenas uma tabela html e nada mais.